# Formatting error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, error-handling, internationalization

We use some self written validations for our applications. These dont use one of the already translated ones like 'empty' or 'invalid'. They are formated by the default way `%{attribute} %{message}`

However, our customers demand to format them in `%{attribute}: %{message}.`, just some added punctuations.

These are the error messages in the base i18n downloaded from gitub:

```
  errors: &errors
    format: "%{attribute} %{message}"

  activemodel:
    errors:
      <<: *errors
  activerecord:
    errors:
      <<: *errors
```

Whenever I change `format`, it does nothing. We are using formtastic.

Comment: Where do you place your change? Have you restarted server after the change?

Comment: it is in locale. And all other translation in this file are working well

Comment: Hi,
i have same issues. Did u find solution ?
Thanks

Comment: It is definitely not enough information... And I am not familiar with formtastic.